# Will jailbreaking my iphone 3g allow me to have instagram?

Tags: iphone, applications, jailbreak

Will jailbreaking my iPhone 3g allow me to install Instagram?

Answer (score 1):

Jailbreaking doesn't change the iOS version installed, so if Instagram requires a newer iOS version than the latest available for the 3G the answer will be *NO*.